# mount and umount behaving differently when run under cron

Tags: mount, cron, centos-6, fuse, umount

Running CentOS 6 in AWS, and what I'm seeing is baffling me.

There is an `s3fs` mount in `/etc/fstab` that sometimes loses its ability to read and write from. I have a cron job that worked great for months, that would simply test that the mount was good every minute, and if it ever lost the connection, it would just `umount` and `mount` the share. The mount tended to go away more often under no load, then under actual load, so this was a great solution.

For some reason this stopped working, and now machines come up unable to read/write from the share, as the first thing the machines do upon boot after provisioning is `umount` and `mount` the share.

Now the error I get when trying to read is this:

```
cp: cannot open `/app/canary.txt' for reading: Input/output error
```

In the `/var/log/messages` I see this:

```
kernel: s3fs[3077]: segfault at e66000 ip 00007f833663d94e sp 00007ffc849c5b18
error 4 in libc-2.12.so[7f83365b4000+18a000]
```

Now, when I run the exact same script in the console as root, it simply works perfectly. Unmounting and mounting the drive and leaving it in a working state.

My first guess was that something in the environment was causing the difference, so I added a `source /root/.bash_profile` to my script, to no avail.

The line in /etc/fstab is a monster, but this is what we found to work best after many attempts at fine tuning:

```
ourbucket /app fuse.s3fs _netdev,allow_other,endpoint=us-west-2,url=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com,use_path_request_style,use_sse,gid=1001,umask=0007,use_cache=/srv/s3fs,retries=20,parallel_count=30,connect_timeout=30,readwrite_timeout=60,stat_cache_expire=86400,max_stat_cache_size=100000 0 0
```

This is what the cronfile looks like:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/sudo /root/check_mount.sh
```

I tried it with and without the sudo, as I thought it may affect the environment.

I've tried many variations of the script, but most of these commands were used at one point or another. The same issue comes up regardless of which type of `umount` I do.

```
\cp /app/canary.txt /tmp/canary.txt
retVal=$?
sleep 1
if [ ${retVal} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Copy failed, trying to umount"
    umount /app
    echo "umount returned $?"
    sleep 1
    echo "Trying umount -f"
    umount -f /app
    echo "umount -f returned $?"
    sleep 1
    echo "Trying fusermount -u"
    /usr/local/bin/fusermount -u /app
    echo "fusermount returned $?"
    sleep 1
    echo "Trying to mount"
    mount /app
    echo "mount returned $?"
    sleep 1
    echo "Trying copy after mount"
    \cp /app/canary.txt /tmp/canary.txt
fi
```

This script was initially in `python`, with the key pieces just shelling out to `os.system`, but I wanted to remove that from the equation. It was giving the same issues.

Comment: "The mount tended to go away more often under no load, then under actual load" -- I think maybe `autofs` may replace your script; however I cannot tell if it will solve your problem. I'm writing this only to let you know such tool exists, maybe you will find it useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my complete solution:

First I visually audited the audit.log. To catch the right things and only the right things, I used `audit2allow` to create a policy and type enforcement rule.

```
grep mount /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -R -M mounts3fs
```

I grep for mount so I only get the right things.

This created a **mounts3fs.pp** and **mounts3fs.te** file. The **mounts3fs.te** looks like this:

```
policy_module(mounts3fs, 1.0)

require {
    type file_t;
    type var_t;
    type mount_t;
    type cert_t;
    class dir { write remove_name add_name };
    class file { create unlink link setattr };
}

#============= mount_t ==============
#!!!! The source type 'mount_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
# user_home_t, etc_runtime_t, var_run_t, mount_var_run_t, mount_tmp_t, user_home_dir_t, etc_t, nfs_t, tmpfs_t, tmp_t, var_t

allow mount_t cert_t:dir { write remove_name add_name };
allow mount_t cert_t:file { create unlink };
allow mount_t file_t:dir { remove_name add_name };
allow mount_t file_t:file { unlink link setattr };
allow mount_t var_t:file link;
```

To install the policy, I run this:

```
semodule -i mounts3fs.pp
```

I found that wasn't quite sufficient for certain operations, so I created an additional policy like this:

```
module s3fs 1.0;

require {
    type file_t;
    type mount_t;
    class dir create;
    class file create;
}

#============= mount_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mount_t file_t:dir create;
allow mount_t file_t:file create;
```

`selinux` can still go straight to hell.

Comment: I will post a full solution once I have it. Basically, `selinux` is blocking read/write on the mounted volume.